# JMeter Distributed Testing slave machines throw Test Fragment file not found

Tags: jmeter

Here is how I configured the distributed testing

1. With 1 Master Machine & 2 Slave Machines - Successfully able to connect
2. Copied the Scripts & Test Data folder on Master Machine
3. On 2 Slave machines copied only Test Data folder
4. Distribution Test from Master Machine for the Given Scenario With 1 Thread & Login also Once with 1 Thread, so my expectation was Login Once and Run the scenario for 2 Threads 1 on Slave1 & another Thread on Slave2

But I am running into the below 2 issues

**Issue#1:** Though I have Given Login No.Of Threads 1& Once -  Login Ran Twice

**Issue#2:** On Both Slave Machines says Login Test Fragment.jmx not found

I am not sure what went wrong
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

1. > Note: The same test plan is run by all the servers. JMeter does not distribute the load between servers, each runs the full test plan. So if you set 1000 Threads and have 6 JMeter server, you end up injecting 6000 Threads.

so if you have 2 slaves you will have 2 Login requests, if you have 3 slaves - you will have 3 Login requests, etc.

2. > If the test uses any data files, note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server.

   so you need to copy your folder containing test fragments onto all slaves, master sends only .jmx test script, any external data (CSV files used in [CSV Data Set Configs](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), .jmx files used in [Include Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller), etc.) need to be copied manually

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)